# keeping on prem access db in sync with SQL Azure

Tags: azure, ms-access, vb6-migration

I am cloud enabling a VB5 Point of sale type application which is installed at 40 store locations using an Access Database ('97). I know- bad idea but that's what my client wants to pay me to do - 250,000 lines of code so no budget to rewrite it.

I plan to create a SQL Azure database and use an API (PaaS) to allow all the locations to use common data.

Each location would only have an average of 100 DB calls to a single Members table for accessing member data and rewards program data.

I would appreciate any ideas for keeping the on prem Access databases in sync with the Azure data. I want to do that in case of loss of internet connection at a location. I don't think I can use Azure SQL Sync because all databases would need to be SQL Server DB's. I am thinking of simply using the local access db as a cache and whenever a member first accesses their member sql data, check if the last update dates are different and if so, update the access db. Maybe a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there was a .net sync provider floating around for Access in 2009, 2010. It was demoed at PDC 2009. Sadly, that sync provider for ms-access was never released to the public. that would have allowed seamless sync to SQL running on the Azure OS.

However, I would thus consider running SQL express on each location. And thus you could make the SQL express edition a replication client (subscriber) to SQL Azure. You could would think/consider the database to be local on your same network, but it would in fact allow all locations to share the same data.

And if there is JUST the tables for the re-wards stuff - a new feature perhaps? Then run SQL server for just that part.  But, if you needed all locations to share data, and a common database, then SQL server sync and replication would work very well, since everything + software would run on a local network, and hit that local edition of SQL express - but the sync part would thus be outside of the application and code base you have now.

If you know what you are doing then a migration from JET/mdb to SQL express can be done without too much effort. It would much center on if the VB app used oleDB, or say ADO in place of say DAO (jet/Access) data objects.

So, if the VB app used ADO, then conversion to using SQL express as the back end would in fact be rather minimal.  So running SQL express on each site these days is easy, and it more relible then Access/JET based back ends (if those sites are mutli-user). I suppose if each site is not multi-user, then JET is a fine dataengine, and that zero install as compared to setting up and running and installing SQL express would suggest you can still use JET.

There is no sync client for Access to SQL server. So, you could consider rolling your own.
(well, you kind of have to). As noted, the other way is to NOT have any sync software in the application part, and use sql server sync (replication) for this purpose. While the free edition of SQL express can't be a master, they can be clients/subscribers to SQL server sync services. So, you don't touch your application, but ONLY migrate to SQL express from JET and then the sync parts are outside of your application.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info.
Unfortunately, the VB app is using VB5 (not 6) and DAO.
Another thing that may be a factor...
Each location has 1 install with a access 97 database and up to 3 other installs that access the same database over the file system. Since the vb app is 250,000 lines of code, I assume changing to ADO would be more work that he is willing to do.
I considered using access linked tables to sync access with sql , but I don't think that will work because we are not using ms access itself, only an acccess database file. I think linked tables would require access to be open.

Comment: Well, I think "ado" might have been around in Vb5 days. But that is VERY moot right now, since the app is not ADO, and thus converting to SQL server would be a big job, not just changing the connection string from JET/ACE to sql server. Had this been ADO, then 99%+ of the existing sql would work as is against SQL server. However, since this is not using the oleDB provider (ADO) and uses DAO, then you can't risk such a code change with such a large code base.

Comment: So, Plan A is no go. You could thus consider some sync routines and roll your own. This would be ok say for 5-10 tables. However, this is likely a big releatioal monster - and rolling a sync routine for related data would of course mean some updates to the existing schema. As noted, you could still consider writing a .net sync framework client for this - it should allow this to occur without schema changes. The problem is that writing that sync provider is a lot of work, and worse the .net sync framework has been depreciated (but I would still use it).

Comment: I agree. I believe I will  update the local db just in time, when a member first accesses his data, compare the local record with the cloud db- if they are different, update the local db. Then he can use the local DB as before since its now up to date. Since the VB5 developer owns that code,  and is more familiar  (I haven't touched it in 22 years). For some other tables such as member rewards, we are moving all that functionality to the cloud so we won't need to worry about updating the access db for that. Currently the member rewards data is in a few columns in the member table.